# How to mimic a HTML Form request in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I made an app using Laravel so most of the pages uses simple HTML Form to send HTTP requests.

I recently decided to use Angular Material to code my front-end, but as all of the input components forces to use ng-model, I want to mimic the behavior of the simple HTML Form Submission using an Angular Controller.

**For example: I want this**

index.html

```
<form action="/confirm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**By using this**

index.html

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">

<form action="/confirm" method="POST" ng-submit="submit($event)">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.submit = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('action');
        var data = {
            name : this.name
        };

        // Some code here that I can't figure out
        // Which will mimic the simple HTML Form Submission

    };
}]);
```

*One solution* is to append a hidden input inside the form for each of the inputs outside the form. I don't want to do it that way, it will be very in-efficient.

Any other ways? Thank You.

And it will be great if anyone knows how to handle this for a file input.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript:**

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = null;

  $scope.submitForm = function(name) {
    //submitting form items depend on what your /confirm endpoint is expecting
    //is it expecting JSON, form data in the body, etc?

    //JSON
    var payload = {
        name: name
    };

    //submitting via FormData
    //var payload = new FormData();
    //payload.append("name", name);

    //use $http to post to server
    $http.post('/confirm/', payload).then(function(response) {
        //success
    }, function() {
        //an error has occurred
    });
  }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm(name)">
    <!-- bind model to input using ng-model -->
    <input required type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm(name)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I can send the data correctly, but it is not redirecting to that page after the request like a html form submission. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Look inside `.then()`.  These are your callback functions on what happens when the server has accepted/rejected the data.  `.then(function(response) { window.location="path/to/next/page";  }).catch(function(response) { alert("uh oh!")l });`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $http service to make http calls you code should look like this

```
var url = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('action');
var data = {
   name : this.name
};
$http({
  method: url,
  url: '/confirm',
  data:data
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```